# from Taylor Series to function

Tags: taylor-expansion

I can't find the logic , how can I find the $f(x)$  and for which x it is defined  when I'm given this : 
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(x-1)^n/2^n$$

I see that $x_0=1$ and somehow reminds me of $1/(1-x)$ but I can't expand this at $x_0=1$

So what logic shall I follow to solve this question ?

Comment: What you have here is a geometric series. Do you know how to handle them? What is the ratio? Btw, is $f(x)$ supposed to be the series? You don't write that...

Comment: I have no problems when finding the series for a certain $f(x)$ but the reverse of it ... well it's not going really well

Comment: @mickep This was my exam question , I was asked only to find the function if I'm given a certain series , and which values of x are valid

Comment: The series is $\sum z^n$ where $z=\frac{x-1}{2}$. You know that (for suitable $z$) we have $\sum z^n=\frac{1}{1-z}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure I get what you want, but if you mean that
$$
f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} (x-1)^n/2^n
$$
then: A geometric sum
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}r^n=\frac{1}{1-r}
$$
provided $|r|<1$. You have this with $r=(x-1)/2$. I guess you can finish from here?

Answer (score 1):

$$|x-1|\lt2\implies f(x)=\frac1{1-\color{red}{(x-1)/2}}=\frac2{3-x}$$

Comment: I just expanded this and got $\frac23\sum(x/3)^n$
how is this the same as my series above ( in the question ) @Did

Comment: Indeed these are power series expansions of the same function around the points $0$ and $1$ respectively, hence the sums of these series coincide on the intersection $B(0,3)\cap B(1,2)=B(1,2)$. (Why did you accept an answer based on the same approach 10 hours ago if the approach escapes you, as your comment shows?)

Comment: I knew I wouldn't get any other answer ...

Comment: Sorry but you are not making any sense. How many other answers did you accept without understanding them?